# Ok. How is this not real?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

[I'm speaking about this one.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38019/is-it-possible-to-hard-brick-nexus-7-with-software-means-or-a-wrong-series-of-c)

The essence of the question is:

*"Is Nexus 7 truly unbrickable (without touching hardware)?"*

The question is important (for obvious reasons), and not rhetorical (for reasons even more obvious).

So, what's wrong?

---

Or should I ask a dozen questions first, starting with:

*"Nexus 7: what a bootloader is and how does it differ from boot?"*

-- and then try to figure it out myself?

Heck, isn't this a "Q&A site"??

Comment: Easy: Because this question is not answerable.

Comment: @Izzy: easy?? What do you mean by "not answerable"? If someone issues `fastboot erase bootloader` and then reboots the Nexus 7, will it be hard-bricked? (it appears, yes, but I'm still not sure, hence the question, pal)

Comment: If you already know it's brickable, the question makes even less sense. And if you don't know, you never can be sure. There's no such thing as 100% proof that something can *NOT* be broken. So the question will, most likely, fall into the category *Chatty, open-ended questions*, which is off topic according to the [FAQ].

Comment: @Izzy If you read my comment, you'll see that I don't know for sure if Nexus 7 is hard-brickable with software means, or not. The question starts with the same statement, giving links to threads where quite experienced people give essentially opposite answers to it. The presence of those links (and the rationale for the question's existence) makes the question somewhat bulkier than a simple "is Nexus 7 hard-brickable with a laptop and a USB cable?", bot does not make it "chatty".

Comment: Besides, if there really is a known way to hard-brick the device by the described means, the question is not open-ended -- there exists an answer to it (which, again, I would like to see -- see my previuos comment) -- and thats exactly why I am asking my question.

Comment: After all asking questions only when there's a guarantee an answer exists would be a strange means to avoid open-ended questions, right? :)

Comment: It's a difference not to know whether an answer exists -- or to know in advance there cannot be a definite answer. For the former: agreed, of course :) But then it might still be closed as soon as it turns out to be leading that way.

Comment: @Izzy OK: so the title "Is it possible (with software means) to put Nexus 7 in a state in which it cannot be made to boot with any _currently known_ software means (i.e. effectively hard-brick)?" will do?

Comment: This I'd call at least border-line -- as you'd either have to expect some all-knowing user -- or turn it into a "poll". There are no *facts* to give (except someone happens to know such a possibility). It might still be theoretically possible. But at ASE, we deal with *facts* -- with *problems and their solutions*. This question would still fall into the category *Speculative questions*, and thus be off topic.

Comment: @Izzy Ok, I already thought about it, the all-knowing user obstacle can be easily removed, what about "Is there a known way to put Nexus 7 (with software means) in a state from which there's no _currently known_ way to make it boot (i.e. essentially hard-brick)?"

Comment: If there is such a way, and someone knows it, he will stand up and point to the dangerous sequence of commands and actions. If not, the question will stay unanswered (but still be a valid one, as one to which there may be an answer, as we agreed above) :)

Comment: So your goal is to brick your device? ;) I'd suggest you switch over to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android) (that's where *discussion* should take place, not here).

Comment: @Izzy My goal is to know whether I can accidentally brick my device (as I state in my question), chat is of no help here.
Putting it straight: do you find the suggested title appropriate?

Answer (score 5):

What circumstances is a general all-round "yes you can" or "no you can't" going to be useful? Are you just going to spend days throwing random commands at your tablet in random ways, or is there something specific that you're trying to do? What are you likely to be doing that has a chance of bricking your device?

A question like "Is there a chance rooting my device using the FancyNamed Rooting Method could brick my device?" is answerable, (and will probably already be answered on the support thread for which ever rooting method you use).

Your question as it is at the moment is very broad, has a lot of unknowns, and isn't really answerable with any answer that will stay the test of time.

Comment: I'm not asking for either plain "Yes" or "No", but rather about is there a possiblity the device will end in a state that requires sending it back to ASUS after a sequence of cammands and actions usually done during flashing ROMS (and the question specifically speaks about that, have you read it through?). Then, since there're conflicting statements on the matter (as I posint out in my question, again, -- see the links), I ask what I ask for: either tell me that the device is "ubrickable" (_and also telll why_), OR point to the dangerous sequence of commands and actions.

Comment: Again, the threads on the internet look silent on the topic I'm interested in (at least several hours of googling and reading gave me the opposite opinions I point to in my question). I strongly doubt, ASUS support will answer this question, too :)

Comment: Putting it short: I have made some prelimenary research, and know what I am asking for; if you guys are not ok with current wording, I can possibly make it better, but the essence of the question stays there, roughly: "Is there a known way to put Nexus 7 (with software means, i.e. during ROM flashing, bootloader unlocking or rooting) in a state from which there's no currently known way to make it boot (i.e. essentially hard-brick)?"

Comment: @mlvljr "Is there a way to recover from `fastboot erase bootloader`?" is an answerable question. "Is it possible to recover from all possible actions that might harm the device software/firmware in ways that haven't been specified?" isn't an answerable question, it's just too general.

Comment: Ok, catch you on that :)

Comment: Edited my question.